# Display the Tifinagh alphabet on Android emulator

Tags: android, unicode, android-emulator

To display Tifinagh characters on Android emulator I tried this method:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.font);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MZTIFIYU.TTF");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

However it didn't work. I still see boxes instead of characters.

Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: What is MZTIFIYU.TTF? Is it a symbol font mapping Tifinagh to arbitrary ASCII letters, or a proper Unicode font providing characters in the U+2D30-7F block?

Comment: it's a proper unicode font for tifinagh characters .

Answer (score 1):

Azul :)
I'm able to see the Tifinagh characters using this font: [t_ircam-webfont.ttf](https://code.google.com/p/asughl/source/browse/tags/1.1/css/t_ircam-webfont.ttf?r=8)

You could also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053719/tifinagh-caracter-not-displayed-on-android-emulator) for additional help.