# Tifinagh character not displayed on Android emulator

Tags: android, fonts, android-emulator, character

As you can see on the attached picture, Eclipse is displaying correctly the [Tifinagh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tifinagh) text from an XML in the resources file.
But When I parse this XML into a listView it doesn't show. I taught it has to do with XML parsing, so I created a new project based on the Hello world tutorial and substituted "Hello world!" with Tifinagh characters (that I copied from the XML) and again; they don't show.

I checked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322347/display-the-tifinagh-alphabet-on-android-emulator) on stackoverflow but it has no answer yet.

So;

1. Does Android support Tifinagh?
2. If not, are there any workarounds to solve this problem?

Thanks for any help.

[image: Tifinagh_not_displayed_on_android_emulator]

### Update

I managed to set the font in the hello world interface by using:

```
// Set the tifinagh font
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "t_ircam-webfont.ttf");               
    TextView tv = (TextView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

But how can I set it for a ListView?

```
    package com.theopentutorials.android.activities;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.theopentutorials.android.beans.PostObj;
import com.theopentutorials.android.xml.XMLPullParserHandler;

public class XMLPullParserActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Prepare the list view to publish item to.
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        List<PostObj> posts = null;
        try {
            XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
            posts = parser.parse(getAssets().open("amawal_posts.xml"));

            System.out.println("============================== ");
            System.out.println("Posts fresh "+ posts);
            System.out.println("============================== ");

            ArrayAdapter<PostObj> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PostObj>(this, R.layout.list_item, posts);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.xmlpull_parser, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more trial and error, I got it working :)
Since I get the raw data from XML to a list view, I had to create a custom adapter, Check the full code:

```
package com.theopentutorials.android.xml;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {

private final Typeface mTypeface;

private List<T> objects; // obviously don't use object, use whatever
                                // you really want

private final Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects) {//Context context, int resource, List<T> objects
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = (List<T>) objects;
    mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "t_ircam-webfont.ttf");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Object obj = objects.get(position);

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    tv.setText(obj.toString()); // use whatever method you want for the
                                // label
    // set whatever typeface you want here as well
    return tv;
}
}
```

And in my Main activity

```
public class XMLPullParserActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Prepare the list view to publish item to.
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        List<PostObj> posts = null;
        try {
            // Parse the XML
            XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
            posts = parser.parse(getAssets().open("amawal_posts.xml"));

            /*System.out.println("============================== ");
            System.out.println("Posts fresh " + posts);
            System.out.println("============================== ");*/

            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter<PostObj>(this, R.layout.list_item, posts));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.xmlpull_parser, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the layout/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</TextView>
```

In the layout/main.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```